# error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘main’

Tags: c++, g++

I am trying to figure out how to jump to one function then come back and preform another. When I compile it the only error I get is

```
error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘main’
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "32PM.cpp"

pm()

int main()
{
  std::cout << "Hello World!";
}
```

Comment: Whats `pm` and what is that `pm()` doing in the middle of nowhere?

Comment: Alright I don't think pm is anything to worry about in this, and the main function was just torn out of a hello world program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function call followed by a semicolon, is a statement. Statements can only be used in a function body. E.g. in the body of `main`.

---

Note that declarations in C++ come in two flavors: block declarations, which can be used as statements in blocks, and non-block declarations, that can only be (directly) used outside functions.

E.g. a variable declaration is a block declaration, and a namespace definition (or for that matter a full function definition) is a non-block declaration.

It's somewhat arbitary, but the essence is that there is divide between constructs that can be used as statements, and those that cannot, and this is part of the C++ grammar.